# EF Core - Multiple Contexts and Transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We are splitting our large DbContext into smaller contexts, each one taking care of a small domain bounded context. The contexts save operations are orchestrated by a unit of work as shown below.

The domain has two bounded contexts, Partners and Employees. The Unit Of Work manages two DbContexts, `PartnerContext` and `EmployeeContext`. We run all save operations within a transaction to ensure the operation is atomic.

A simplified version of the problem is available on [github](https://github.com/TOuhrouche/EF-DDD)

```
public class UnitOfWork {

  public Task SaveChanges(){
      // EmployeeContext begins a transaction and shares it with other contexts
      var strategy = employeeContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
      return strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
      {
        await using var transaction = await employeeContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        await partnerContext.Database.UseTransactionAsync(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
        await partnerContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await employeeContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
      });
  }
}
```

The following code works fine. Changes are all executed within one single transaction

```
   var unitOfWork = new unitOfWork();
   ... perform updates to both contexts
   await unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

However, the following code throws when attempting to save changes a second time.

```
   var unitOfWork = new unitOfWork();
   ... perform updates to both contexts
   await unitOfWork.SaveChanges(); <-- Work fine
   ... doing a bit more work
   await unitOfWork.SaveChanges(); <-- Crashes
```

The line above fails with `The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction.` error message.

The resulting SQL log is:

```
**** The first save operation logs start here:
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [Person] ([Discriminator], [ManagerId], [Name])
    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
    SELECT [Id]
    FROM [Person]
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Committing transaction.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Disposing transaction.

**** The second save operation logs start here:
    
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Debug: Opening connection to database 'EF_DDD' on server 'localhost'.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Debug: Opened connection to database 'EF_DDD' on server 'localhost'.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Unspecified'.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Began transaction with isolation level 'ReadCommitted'.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction: Debug: Disposing transaction.
```

Would anyone know the reason behind the second `unitOfWork.SaveChanges()` complaining about an open transaction despite the fact the first transaction was committed and disposed (as you can see from the logs above)?

**Update**

I removed all async code and the execution strategy (retry) to narrow the issue down, the code now looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employeeContext = new EmployeeContext(ConnectionString);
        var partnersContext = new PartnersContext(employeeContext.Database.GetDbConnection());
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        unitOfWork.Update(employeeContext, partnersContext, 1);
        unitOfWork.Update(employeeContext, partnersContext, 2);

    }

    public class UnitOfWork
    {
        public void Update(EmployeeContext employeeContext, PartnersContext partnerContext, int count)
        {
            partnerContext.Partners.Add(new Partner($"John Smith {count}"));
            employeeContext.Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = $"Richard Keno {count}" });

            using var trans = employeeContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
            partnerContext.Database.UseTransaction(trans.GetDbTransaction());
            partnerContext.SaveChanges();
            employeeContext.SaveChanges();
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

The first one goes through, and the database is updated, but the second call fails with the error below.

[image]

**Update 2**

Using `TransactionScope` instead of `BeginTransaction` seems to work. The following code works and updates the database accordingly.

```
        var strategy = employeeContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            using var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
            partnerContext.Partners.Add(new Partner($"John Smith {count}"));
            employeeContext.Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = $"Richard Keno {count}" });
            await partnerContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            await employeeContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            scope.Complete();
        });
```

Comment: This may have to do with your async processing. The `await` in `await strategy.ExecuteAsync` will return control to the caller and allow execution to continue on the main thread. So when you get to `unitOfWork.SaveChanges();` the first time, it will fire off the transaction, and then immediately try to perform your "*... doing a bit more work*" and then again immediately call  `unitOfWork.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: That being said, does your code actually work? I don't think c# allows the `await` operator in a method without the `async` modifier.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 Just gave that a try, the second save is still failing despite removing the await. I even tried stepping through the code one statement at a time so I have control over the execution thread, still the second save fails.

Comment: Stepping through doesn't necessarily give you the control you are looking for when it comes to async code. Also, your `strategy.ExecuteAsync` will do the same thing as I described above because you `await` within that as well. You may need to capture the task that is saving, and ensure that the task has completed before calling save the next time.

Comment: Your method must be `public async Task SaveChangesAsync()` instead of `public void SaveChanges()`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov that still shouldn't compile if they are using `await` within the method. The method signature would still need to use the `async` modifier. If that's not the case I would appreciate if someone could provide me the source to read up on regarding using `await` within a synchronous method. EDIT: The modification you added to include `async` in the signature should help.

Comment: @GETah See this resource pertaining to the execution flow of asynchronous code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod

Comment: @Ibrennan208 @Alexander Petrov Thank you for the tips. I changed the code to return a `Task` from `SaveChanges` and `awaited` the save operations. I still get an exception while trying to save.

Comment: Is it the same exception? Or has the exception changed?

Comment: The same exception. I followed the MS guidelines as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency - it is still failing. You can find the full version of the source code here: https://github.com/TOuhrouche/EF-DDD

Comment: Are the two DbContexts connecting to the same database?  If so you'll get better perf and won't be tied to Windows if you simply share a DbConnection between the two DbContexts.  If not, you need a real distributed transaction, which is pretty much an antipattern.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, both contexts talk to the same database. The first context shares its db connection with the second one. In fact, the transaction fails if the two contexts aren't operating on the same connection.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft is DTC an antiipattern?

Comment: Ok, so I think you can simply omit the UseTransactionAsync since the underlying connection already has an active transaction.

Comment: " is DTC an antiipattern" there are scenarios where it makes sense, but for modern microservice apps, it's an antipattern.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - The transaction is required so the second context can use it. All contexts managed by the unit of work must share the same transaction, so the different save operations are atomic.

Comment: I just tried to repro this behavior and could not.  Try to remove your UoW wrapper and produce a simplified repro with just the EF primitives.  It's suspicious that you see "Opening connection to database 'EF_DDD' on server 'localhost'." because to share a connection between DbContexts you need to keep it open.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Have you tried the code I shared here: https://github.com/TOuhrouche/EF-DDD? I found out that the issue appears only when there are two or more contexts sharing the same connection/transaction.

Comment: No.  I used the code in my answer below.

Comment: I removed the async and the strategy code to keep the bare minimum, but the code still fails. I think the problem is related to EF having to juggle two contexts over the same database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are hitting some internal EF Core 3 implementation defect/bug which has been fixed down the road, because the issue does not reproduce in the latest at this time EF Core 6.0 (but *does* reproduce in EF Core 3.1).

The problem is with cleanup of the shared underlying db connection and db transaction. It can be solved (which also helps the future EF Core versions) by disposing the EF Core transaction wrapper (`IDbContextTransaction`) returned by the `UseTransaction{Async}` call, e.g.

```cs
using var trans2 = await partnerContext.Database.UseTransactionAsync(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
```

or

```cs
using var trans2 = partnerContext.Database.UseTransaction(trans.GetDbTransaction());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried forcing the disposal `trans.Dispose()` of the transaction with no luck

Comment: Update: I just tried using `TransactionScope` instead (see Update 2) and it works. The code works as expected (I also updated the github repo)

Comment: @GETah With the original usage of `DbTransaction`, you need to dispose the `trans2` returned by `UseDbTransaction(trans)`, not `trans` variable returned by `BeginTransasction`. It's because the `trans` owns the underlying `DbTransaction` while `trans2` doesn't - it just needs proper cleanup, which `Dispose` of the EF Core wrapper object does. Using distributed transaction (`TransactionScope`) looks overkill for such usage scenario (`DbContext`s with shared `DbConnection`).

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it! Disposing of trans2 worked like a charm! I edited my github repo and added a separate method `UpdateFixed` to highlight the fix.